# Android draw transparency

Tags: android, graphics, transparency

I'm new to Android (and Java for that matter), and I'm making a simple game. I'm stuck.

My problem is this:

I have 2 png images (a background and foreground) that take up the whole screen on startup. I now want to be able to set the width of the "drawn portion" of the foreground to the x-coordinate of ON_DRAG. My control method works fine; it's used like this:

g.drawRect(0, 0, scene.getLine(), g.getHeight(), Color.GREEN);

where scene.getLine() returns the x-value of the touch. So at this point I can draw a green rectangle above my images. But what I actually want is for those rectangle dimensions to "punch a hole" in my top-layer png (so the background is revealed beneath). I do not want to scale the foreground.

I have tried clipRect, but it doesnt work because I have other images that need to be drawn on top of these two, and clipRect prevents this. I have looked at a bunch of "PorterDuffXfermode" code, but cannot understand how to apply it to my situation, and cannot make it work. i.e. I can make a Paint with the PorterDuff "SRC" mode set, but I dont know how to define "source" and "destination" images so the Paint will work its magic. A final consideration with this is that even if the PorterDuff would work, Im not sure it would be practical given that I want this thing to run at 60fps.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `canvas.save()` before a clip and `canvas.restore()` after your drawing to return the canvas to the sate it was in before you stared. Then you can draw your additional images.